# How can I locate elements by their locator (ID, name, XPath, or CSS) in dynamically generated HTML code using Selenium WebDriver in Java?

Tags: java, angular, selenium-webdriver, ionic-framework

"This is my Angular code:

```
<ion-button slot="end" *ngIf="auditData.id == null" (click)="presentActionSheet(section.sectionId)" id="secMedia{{i+section.sectionId}}">
    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="attach-outline" style="color:black;font-size: 200%;"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

When I click the ion-button, it calls the presentActionSheet(section.sectionId) function in Ionic Angular TypeScript.

```
async presentActionSheet(sectionId: number) {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        header: 'Choose the type of media to be uploaded',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Image',
                icon: 'camera',
                handler: () => {
                    this.clickImage(sectionId);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Video',
                icon: 'videocam',
                handler: () => {
                    this.recordVideo(sectionId);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Files',
                icon: 'document',
                handler: () => {
                    this.userInputElement.click();
                    this.currentSecId = sectionId;
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                data: {
                    action: 'cancel',
                },
            },
        ],
    });

    await actionSheet.present();
}
```

At that time, it generates dynamic HTML code, ie;

```
<button type="button" class="action-sheet-button ion-activatable ion-focusable sc-ion-action-sheet-md">   
    <span class="action-sheet-button-inner sc-ion-action-sheet-md">
        <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" class="action-sheet-icon sc-ion-action-sheet-md md hydrated" role="img">  </ion-icon>Image
    </span>
    <ion-ripple-effect class="sc-ion-action-sheet-md md hydrated" role="presentation">
    </ion-ripple-effect>
</button>
<button type="button" class="action-sheet-button ion-activatable ion-focusable sc-ion-action-sheet-md">
    <span class="action-sheet-button-inner sc-ion-action-sheet-md">
        <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" class="action-sheet-icon sc-ion-action-sheet-md md hydrated" role="img"></ion-icon>
        Video
    </span>
    <ion-ripple-effect class="sc-ion-action-sheet-md md hydrated" role="presentation"></ion-ripple-effect>
</button>
<button type="button" class="action-sheet-button ion-activatable ion-focusable sc-ion-action-sheet-md">
    <span class="action-sheet-button-inner sc-ion-action-sheet-md">
        <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" class="action-sheet-icon sc-ion-action-sheet-md md hydrated" role="img"></ion-icon>
        Files
    </span>
    <ion-ripple-effect class="sc-ion-action-sheet-md md hydrated" role="presentation"></ion-ripple-effect>
</button>
```

So, how do I write a script using Selenium WebDriver in Java to click on an image, video, or file? How do I locate?"

I am trying to locate an element using XPath, which I copied from the UI, but it doesn't seem to find the element. Instead, I'm encountering an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your application's behaviour.

For Dynamic Elements, the first thing we check is the pattern.

What attribute value remains the same?

```
//button[@class='action-sheet-button ion-activatable ion-focusable sc-ion-action-sheet-md']
```

If not the whole attribute value, what part of the attribute remains the same?

```
//button[contains(@class, 'action-sheet-button')]
```

If you want to click the image within the element button:

```
//button[contains(@class, 'action-sheet-button')]//*[@role='img']
```

If you want to click the element using one Dynamic Xpath only:

```
//When declaring dynamic element
By dynamicBtnClassRole = By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, '%s')]//*[@role='%s']");

//Then when you find for an element
WebElement elmButton = driver.findElement(dynamicBtnClassRole.asBy(strClass, strRole);
elmButton.click();
```

The answer depends on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my TypeScript code to generate unique identifiers for buttons dynamically. Here is the modified code:

```
async presentActionSheet(sectionId: number) {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        header: 'Choose the type of media to be uploaded',
        backdropDismiss: false,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Image',
                icon: 'camera',
                role: 'img',
                handler: () => {
                    this.clickImage(sectionId);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Video',
                icon: 'videocam',
                role: 'video',
                handler: () => {
                    this.recordVideo(sectionId);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Files',
                icon: 'document',
                role: 'file',
                handler: () => {
                    this.userInputElement.click();
                    this.currentSecId = sectionId;
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                data: {
                    action: 'cancel',
                },
            },
        ],
    });

    await actionSheet.present();

    // Assign unique IDs to the buttons after the ActionSheet is presented
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.action-sheet-button');
    buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
        const role = button.getAttribute('role');
        if (role) {
            button.id = `${role}-button-${index}`;
        }
    });
}
```

With this modification, the dynamically generated HTML code now includes a unique class name 'action-sheet-file'.
for example:

```
<button type="button" class="action-sheet-button ion-activatable ion-focusable action-sheet-file sc-ion-action-sheet-md">
    <span class="action-sheet-button-inner sc-ion-action-sheet-md">
        <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" class="action-sheet-icon sc-ion-action-sheet-md md hydrated" role="img"></ion-icon>
        Files
    </span>
    <ion-ripple-effect class="sc-ion-action-sheet-md md hydrated" role="presentation"></ion-ripple-effect>
</button>
```

Here is the Selenium script to click on the button with the unique class name:

```
By dynamicBtnClassRole = By.cssSelector("button.action-sheet-file");
WebElement elmButton = driver.findElement(dynamicBtnClassRole);
elmButton.click();
```